# An embedding of a real line $L$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ not extendible to an automorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

[Abhyankar-Moh theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhyankar%E2%80%93Moh_theorem) says that if $L$ is a complex line in the complex affine plane $\mathbb{C}^2$, then every embedding of $L$ into $\mathbb{C}^2$ extends to an automorphism of the plane.

> Is it possible to replace $\mathbb{C}$ by $k$, where $k$ is:
>   **(1)** any algebraically closed field of characteristic zero? I guess that the answer is yes.
>   **(2)** any field of characteristic zero? Perhaps there exists an easy counterexample with $k=\mathbb{R}$.
>   **(3)** any (commutative) integral domain of characteristic zero?

Any comments are welcome!

**Edit:** **(1)** [This explanation](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Abhyankar%E2%80%93Moh_theorem) about Abhyankar-Moh results is relevant.

**(2)** From the discussion in the comments, my first question has a positive answer due to Theorem 1.6, and my second question should have a counterexample over $\mathbb{R}$. The comments are good, since they clarify my question.

Comment: (1) and (2) hold.

Comment: @blueInk, thank you for your comment. Please, when you say that (2) holds, do you mean that we can replace $\mathbb{C}$ by any field of characteristic zero?

Comment: I was going to say that I would be surprised if Abhyankar didn't write it already in that form. It took a while to find the original paper, but then [he didn't disappoint](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0276?tify=%7B%22view%22%3A%22info%22%2C%22pages%22%3A%5B152%5D%7D)

Comment: I have his paper, but he talks about a result over any field of characteristic zero; however, the theorem I was asking about relies also on other results which are over $\mathbb{C}$ (or, I think, any algebraically closed field of characteristic zero).

Comment: Eh? The paper has the theorem for any characteristic.

Comment: But the result of his paper is not the one I was asking about. Can you please refer to the exact theorem you are talking about?

Comment: His main theorem 1.1 is not what I was asking about (but you are right that any characteristic in it is ok).

Comment: I see that it is 1.6 the one that you want.

Comment: Yes, thanks, and it is over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.. So there should be a counterexample over $\mathbb{R}$, I guess.

Comment: From the argument I don't thing they need that the field is algebraically closed. Assume that $\alpha:k[x,y]\to k[z]$ is epimorphism. Then, by (1.2) there is $\delta:k[x,y]\to k[x,y]$ tame $k$-automorphism such that $\gamma=\alpha\delta$ satisfies $\gamma(y)=0$ and $\gamma(y)=z$. So, $\gamma$ is your automorphism. It just just know in addition that it is tame (although all of them are tame by 1.5).

Comment: Thank you. Truly, this is what I first thought, but then why in 1.6 $k$ is required to be algebraically closed? Maybe I do not need 1.6, since 1.2 is enough, so you were right after all? But then why in https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Abhyankar%E2%80%93Moh_theorem $k$ is required to be algebraically closed?